# How to use subfolders in 'src/' in R packages?

Tags: r, rcpp

C or C++ code inside subfolders in the `src/` for example `src/libfoo` don't get compiled when I install a package.

When I searched on other questions I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18594574/3297472) that mentions Makevars. I searched the [Matrix package Makevars](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/master/src/Makevars). I I thought that I should add:

```
PKG_LIBS: -Llibfoo
```

But that didn't work.

I also found that on [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Compiling-in-sub_002ddirectories). I added the following to my Makevars and It didn't work either.

```
SOURCES = $(libfoo/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
```

How should I tweak the Makevars file?

Comment: Read (and understand) the rest of [Matrix's Makevars](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/master/src/Makevars), and contrast it with the vanilla ones you get from `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` (and used by most Rcpp-using packages).

Comment: Sorry. I didn't find any `Makevars` file on vanilla `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe so vanilla it doesn't need one.  Take `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` -- it's a one liner!  Whereas the one from  Matrix is dozens of lines -- and there is your answer.  This is *much* harder.  In short: _your_ responsibility `libfoo.a` gets built.

Comment: Also, generally not just `-Llibfoo` as you need `-l...` too.  So maybe `-Llibfoo -lfoo` if there is a `libfoo/libfoo.a`.

Comment: Alright! Thanks, will try that!

Comment: This is somewhat of an old post by now, and (incridibly) still one that gives life to a lot of confusion. This [github-repo](https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-headers-subdirs) has an example of automatic inclusion for subdirectories, for anyone (like me) stumbling upon this in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It ended up working by setting:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard libfoo/*.c)
OBJECTS = foo.o RcppExports.o $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
```

The really mysterious part for me is the `wildcard` when defining the `SOURCES`.

Comment: If it works it is good enough :)   This is a seriously underdocumented corner, and it is generally recommended (on r-devel or r-package-devel) to do the least possible to not get into the way of R. And least-possible is what you did here: your sources go straight into the main shared library as if they'd been in `src/` all along.

Comment: Check though if `wildcard` is permitted or if you are now in the "oh dear it is a GNU make extension" corner (which you can settle via `SystemRequirements:` if need be,

Comment: Thanks for this! I found a version elsewhere that omitted `RcppExports.o` from `OBJECTS`. Everything compiled/loaded fine, but I got the dreaded "function not available for .Call" error at runtime. This version works perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me after removing `foo.o RcppExports.o`.  Presumably these are object files created by other C files in the root `src` directory?